# Cannot change subtile's text color in Python PPTX

Tags: python, python-pptx

I've got a title page where I want to change the text color, but where I seemingly am unable to.

```
        slide_register = self.pres.slide_layouts[0]
        slide = self.pres.slides.add_slide(slide_register)
        title = slide.shapes.title
        title.text = 'title text'
        title.text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.color.rbg = RBGColor(100,100,100) # some color
        subtitle = slide.placeholders[1]
        subtitle.text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.color.rbg = RBGColor(100,100,100) # some color
        subtitle.text = 'subtitle text'
```

No matter what colors I choose it always comes out as black title text and grey subtitle text. I'm not getting any errors, so there's some overwriting going on somewhere? I'm able to change the font color in my other slides, just not this one.

Answer (score 0):

Look up "run". That's the stylable element within a paragraph.